# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified- MP3- to WAV conversion

Tags: python, pydub

I am trying to convert .mp3 format file to .wav format file using following code:

```
from pydub import *
input_file = "input.mp3"
output_file = "result.wav"
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(input_file)
sound.export(output_file, format="wav")
```

the file is also in the directory but i am getting below error:

```
PS D:\Fiverr\AudioToText> & C:/Users/intag/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe d:/Fiverr/AudioToText/finalcode.py
C:\Users\intag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:170: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
C:\Users\intag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:198: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work
  warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Fiverr\AudioToText\finalcode.py", line 73, in <module>
    convert_mp3_to_wav()
  File "d:\Fiverr\AudioToText\finalcode.py", line 61, in convert_mp3_to_wav
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(input_file)
  File "C:\Users\intag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 796, in from_mp3
    return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3', parameters=parameters)
  File "C:\Users\intag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 728, in from_file
    info = mediainfo_json(orig_file, read_ahead_limit=read_ahead_limit)
  File "C:\Users\intag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 274, in mediainfo_json
    res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\intag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\intag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: The problem is here: "Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe...". I understand that pydub library is a wrapper. Try to install ffprobe or avprobe

Comment: i have installed the ffprobe but still showing the same error. no change

Comment: also ffprobe is warning not an error.

Comment: maybe the problem is path envirorment variables is not properly configured